# TypeError: event.preventDefault is not a function FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Прекрасно работала отправка формы через ajax, но внезапно выяснилось, что в мозиле не работает. И я никак не пойму, как исправить.

```
<form method="post" action="" id="zakaz" name="zakaz" onsubmit="Otpravka('messegeResult', 'zakaz', '/path.php')">

<script>
function Otpravka(result_id,zakaz,url) {
           event.preventDefault();
                jQuery.ajax({
                url:     url,
                type:     "POST",
                dataType: "html",
                data: jQuery("#"+zakaz).serialize(),  
         success: function(response) { },
error: function(response) {
            document.getElementById(result_id).innerHTML = "<p>Возникла ошибка при отправке формы. Попробуйте еще раз</p>";
            }
         });
         $(':input','#zakaz')
            .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
            .val('')            
}
         </script>
```

Пытаюсь вставить event внутрь (result_id,zakaz,url) - не получается, вместо - тоже.

Comment: Забыл ошибку указать: TypeError: event.preventDefault is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Firefox нет глобального объекта `event`, но в инлайн-обработчиках событий он присутствует.

```js
function Otpravka(evt, result_id, zakaz, url) {
  console.log("Event type: ", evt.type);
  evt.preventDefault();
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    data: jQuery("#" + zakaz).serialize(),
    success: function(response) {},
    error: function(response) {
      document.getElementById(result_id).innerHTML = "<p>Возникла ошибка при отправке формы. Попробуйте еще раз</p>";
    }
  });
  $(':input', '#zakaz')
    .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
    .val('');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="" id="zakaz" name="zakaz"
  onsubmit="Otpravka(event, 'messegeResult', 'zakaz', '/path.php')">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<div id="messegeResult"></div>
```